# Zimbabwean with both parents from the UK - Citizenship

Tags: uk-citizenship

I find myself in a weird situation which I need clarification for. I was born in May 1983 in Zimbabwe and have a Zimbabwe passport. Both my parents hold a British passport and were British from birth. My Grandfather was a British citizen. Does this qualify me as British Citizen? If so what would be the procedure to obtain a passport and citizenship from abroad, specifically from Italy?

Comment: Were your parents born in the UK, or British through UK-born parents? It makes a difference

Comment: HI. They were British through UK born Grand dad, not born in the UK

Comment: Most likely you are **not** a British citizen. Can you please add where (which country) your parents were born, as it might make a difference

Comment: Dad in Zambia at the time northern Rhodesia and mum in Zimbabwe at the time Rhodesia

Comment: I would start by asking at the UK consulate.  Also, with a name like Fabrizio Mazzoni, you might want to look into the possibility that you have inherited Italian citizenship.

Comment: Hi the question was phrased by me but does not apply for me but for my partner. Indeed I am Italian.

Answer (score 4):

If you are born abroad in 1983 then you are a British citizen (by descent) if

1. your mother was a British citizen by birth.
2. your father was a British citizen by birth, and he was married to your mother when you were born

British citizen by birth means that they were born in the UK and Colonies. Unfortunately, Rhodesia (North or South) was not considered as part of the [UK and Colonies since 1949](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/268040/ukandcolonies.pdf) (the Southern part was considered as an independent Commonwealth state), meaning they are most likely not British citizens by birth, which would also mean you are not a British citizen.

Here I was always assuming that both of your parents were born after 1949. If they were born before 1949, then there might be a few (very complex) changes, that might apply, but in most cases it would still mean you are not considered as a British citizen.